# Google Chrome on Ubuntu ignores proxy settings

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Google Chrome with proxy settings for more than a year now, those are the settings I am using:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --proxy-server=“socks5://127.0.0.1:1080”
```

With every update I had the problem that I had to redo the changes in the .desktop file.

Right now Chrome seems to ignore the setting and connects without a proxy.

Chrome version: Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I don't even have an idea where I could look for reasons. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you check this from the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

I have a new tool to save my notes and I have the parameter saved there and just copy&paste it to the desktop file. It saves a “ instead of a ". Slightly different, but it doesn't work.

Looks like it works without those anyway.